# UseDefaultWebProxy Functioning in WPF application

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I have consumed a webservice in my wpf application. In app.config the settings in binding for the webservice has a property as UseDefaultWebProxy=true, Now my question is I want that the default proxy settings must be used from my default web browser say firefox, safari, etc but not from internet explorer(this is not default now).

Please suggest.

Comment: What has the browser proxy setting to do with the webservice property? it is difficult to tell what is being asked here, can you please elaborate?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951523/how-can-i-set-an-http-proxy-webproxy-on-a-wcf-client-side-service-proxy

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967758/what-is-the-purpose-of-usedefaultwebproxy-in-wcf

Comment: Thanks @SalientBrain. I have no idea about WCF, but I wouldn't use any system/user configuration for an application/interface/service. These things don't belong together.