# Fiddler Not Capturing WCF traffic but capturing ASMX fine

Tags: wcf, fiddler

I have been capturing traffic using Fiddler for some ASMX services that call other ASMX services. In this case, I have a simple WCF service calling those ASMX services. It won't capture any traffic. The only wrinkle is that it is using IIS not IISExpress `(http://localhost/Interface12Service/Interface12Service.svc)`. How can I capture WCF traffic?

Answer (score 7):

The Microsoft .NET Framework is hardcoded to bypass proxies for any request to `http://localhost`. To capture such requests in Fiddler or any other proxy, use

> `http://machinename:port/`

or

> `http://localhost.fiddler:port/`

as the target URL.

Comment: I didn't want to believe this was the answer.. or it would even work... but it did!

Answer (score 1):

By default, Fiddler will not capture the traffic. If you want it to capture the traffic, change the client proxy base address to your machine name or to your IP (for instance: 127.0.0.1). This should do the trick. If not, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7506427/375304).

Comment: Alternatively, you can also use WireShark or try [Charles proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/).

Comment: Charles is also a proxy and is subject to exactly the same limitations as any other proxy.

Answer (score 0):

It could just be that fiddler has difficulty picking up traffic from localhost
Try changing the address to `http://localhost./Interface12Service/Interface12Service.svc`

(Notice the dot after localhost.)  This is a common hack for working with Fiddler.

Comment: How can set that if I am debugging an IIS service and it goes right to the IIS Test Client? There is no opportunity to change the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible issue is related to `WCF` client (this may also include other clients but i'm not sure). 
The client can be configured not to use the machine default proxy, which makes the client/application bypass Fiddler capture.

For further reading: [What is the purpose of usedefaultwebproxy in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967758/what-is-the-purpose-of-usedefaultwebproxy-in-wcf).